# Java: How to pause 1 class from running?

Tags: java

when I use `Thread.sleep();`, it pauses my entire program. Is there anything that pauses one class without using multithreading?

Answer (score 4):

You don't pause classes, you pause threads. In the moment you pause your only thread, you pause you entire application as well. So there is no way to pause your only thread and expect the application will continue to run. You would need more than one thread if you expect your application do more than just waiting.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confusing some concepts here.  Classes and Objects do not run.  Threads run, and what they run are the instructions (code) defined by classes and objects.

So no, you cannot pause a Class or Object, only a Thread.  Moreover, if your application is single threaded, then you only have a "main" thread, and if you pause that thread then your whole application will pause.

Comment: objects do not define code; only classes. An object is an instance of a class and only has memory allocated for the defined object variables; the code is shared for all instances of the same class. ...with the small exception of classes that are used to generate or load code at runtime in which case an object of that class may have bytecode in memory (heap) temporarily but it's not executable until loaded by the JVM.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pause a "class" per se. A class is just a "dead" container.

What you can do is pause a thread or a task.

Typically, you would create a separate thread to run the task you want to pause, and pause it when you like - because it runs in a separate thread, it will not hang you whole program.

See this simple example which you can run to better understand how threads can run in parallel:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Runnable lazyTask = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Lazy: I feel like sleeping for a second");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            System.out.println("Lazy: I feel better now");
        }
    };

    new Thread(lazyTask).start();
    //Let's wait a bit until the lazy task goes to sleep
    Thread.sleep(100);
    //now you can do something that will not hang
    System.out.println("Main: I'm sleeping too, but only half a second");
    Thread.sleep(500);
    System.out.println("Main: And I can continue my job while that lazy task is still asleep");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot. You have the main thread . Sleep will pause it. If you want stop run something without affect the main thread you need to fork it from the main thread , by use addiotnal thread